# Not able to map Nginx Port 80 with docker container port 80

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm running a NodeJS app that is running on port 4242 and here's the dockefile, docker-compose and nginx conf looks like this

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12-alpine
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4242
CMD node index.js.
```

**Docker Compose**

```
services:
   web:
      build: .
   ports:
      - "80:4242"
   environment:
   DATABASE_URL: <DB_URL>
   depends_on:
      - db
command: >
    npm run start"
```

**NGINX**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name server_name;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
}
}
```

I wanted to make this app accessible via port 80 through Nginx along with with basic auth on port 80 but I'm not able to map the port correctly.

**EDIT:** I always get port already in use error because Nginx by default is listening on port 80 whereas and in docker-compose I'm mapping 80 with the 4242 which Dockerfile is exposing

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: the best solution is to separate Nginx and Node in two container.in your case there is a conflict with Nginx and port you had mapped. NB: be sure your container is started "docker ps"

Comment: I always get port already in use error because Nginx by default is listening on port 80 whereas and in docker-compose I'm mapping 80 with the 4242 which Dockerfile is exposing. @jordanvrtanoski

Comment: @SeddikOmar I get that running Nginx on a different port would be good but I'm using Nginx just for the basic auth over my Nodejs app for the temp use case

Comment: You get port already in use since there is another process that is using the port 80 on the host.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski please check the edit and my reply to Jonas's answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't have both nginx and docker container on port 80.

They must listen to different ports to avoid "port already in use error".

You could map the container port 4242 to host port 4242 : replace `- "80:4242"` by `- "4242:4242"` in docker-compose file.

Restart your container with `docker-compose restart web`, you can check that your container is running with `docker-compose ps` (you'll see mapped ports at the same time)

Then, you have to change nginx conf accordingly :

```
server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    your_server_name;

  location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4242;
  }
}
```

Notes :

- I removed `try_files` as it was bypassing the `proxy_pass` instruction. Please provide context if you try to achieve something else with `try_files`.
- Replace `your_server_name` with your real server name.
- reload nginx

In the end you have :

1. nginx (directly on host) listening on port 80,
2. `location` block with basic auth,
3. forwarding traffic to host port 4242,
4. which is mapped to docker container port 4242 with `proxy_pass`,
5. Finally hitting your NodeJS app.

Comment: but I also want the Nginx basic auth on the server which should prompt the user for username and password, let's say I do `proxy_pass localhost:4242` then auth doesn't work in this case, I'm thinking maybe it's because I've put the auth`auth_basic "Restricted Content";` on 80 and If I define another block for 4242 then I'll get port already in use error.

Comment: The error "port is already allocated." this means that there is another container using the same port. If you get "bind: address already in use." this means that there is another process on the host using the port. Which error you have?

Comment: @Magnotta My answer already addressed the "port already in use" problem, that is the conflict I was speaking about. Fixing your nginx conf is another topic, basic auth as nothing to do with listening port, it should work (I edited my answer with an example and more instructions). What do you mean by "then auth doesn't work" ? there is no login/password prompt ? or do you have a nginx error ?

Comment: Your answer works but I wanted server to be accessible on both the ports 80 and 4242 but currently on 4242 auth comes just once and it works fine but when I try to access the server via port 80, auth prompt comes on every page.
I don't want auth to appear again during the session if the user has already provided their credentials once.

Comment: @Magnotta "I wanted server to be accessible on both the ports 80 and 4242" This is not what you asked. I'm not sure I fully understand, the auth issue seems strange. With my answer `http://your_server_name` should ask auth only once, `http://your_server_name:4242` should hit your nodejs app directly without auth (replace `your_server_name` accordingly). Please provide more details, what it is you're trying to achieve here ? (maybe give updated nginx conf file, also do you have an auth mecanism directly in your app, which may be in conflict with nginx basic auth ?), thanks.